# MkMapview Crashes on iphone 5s ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, mkmapview

App crashses everytime the Mapview appears.here is the crash log

```
Incident Identifier: *****
CrashReporter Key:   ******
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,1
Process:             **** [3841]
Path:                ****
Identifier:          *****
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-03-20 22:58:50.614 -0400
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.3 (11B511)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x2f19ee83 0x394ff6c7 0x2f19eb89 0x3036aa19 0x3036ac5b 0x19d101 0x3193d73f 0x3193dbcd 0x319e9dbb 0x31ab51e9 0x31a399e3 0x31afa5a9 0x3195ae6d 0x3195aab7 0x3195a9cf 0x315b0413 0x399e40af 0x399e69a9 0x2f1695b1 0x2f167e7d 0x2f0d2471 0x2f0d2253 0x33e062eb 0x31987845 0xea0f3 0xea0a8)

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39aaf1fc 0x39a9c000 + 78332
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39b16a4f 0x39b13000 + 14927
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39a60029 0x39a16000 + 303145
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38eae98b 0x38eae000 + 2443
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38ec76e3 0x38eae000 + 104163
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x394ff937 0x394f7000 + 35127
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38ec51b1 0x38eae000 + 94641
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38ec4a05 0x38eae000 + 92677
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x394ff797 0x394f7000 + 34711
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2f19eb85 0x2f0ca000 + 871301
10  MapKit                          0x3036aa15 0x3032e000 + 248341
11  MapKit                          0x3036ac57 0x3032e000 + 248919
12  FishCacher                      0x0019d0fd 0xe6000 + 749821
13  UIKit                           0x3193d73b 0x31918000 + 153403
14  UIKit                           0x3193dbc9 0x31918000 + 154569
15  UIKit                           0x319e9db7 0x31918000 + 859575
16  UIKit                           0x31ab51e5 0x31918000 + 1692133
17  UIKit                           0x31a399e1 0x31918000 + 1186273
18  UIKit                           0x31afa5a5 0x31918000 + 1975717
19  UIKit                           0x3195ae6b 0x31918000 + 274027
20  UIKit                           0x3195aab3 0x31918000 + 273075
21  UIKit                           0x3195a9cb 0x31918000 + 272843
22  QuartzCore                      0x315b040f 0x3159d000 + 78863
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x399e40ad 0x399e3000 + 4269
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x399e69a5 0x399e3000 + 14757
25  CoreFoundation                  0x2f1695ad 0x2f0ca000 + 652717
26  CoreFoundation                  0x2f167e79 0x2f0ca000 + 646777
27  CoreFoundation                  0x2f0d246d 0x2f0ca000 + 33901
28  CoreFoundation                  0x2f0d224f 0x2f0ca000 + 33359
29  GraphicsServices                0x33e062e7 0x33dff000 + 29415
30  UIKit                           0x31987841 0x31918000 + 456769
31  FishCacher                      0x000ea0ef 0xe6000 + 16623
32  FishCacher                      0x000ea0a4 0xe6000 + 16548

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39a9c838 0x39a9c000 + 2104
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x399eb0d1 0x399e3000 + 32977
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x399e561f 0x399e3000 + 9759
```

here is my code

```
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];

[[LDAnnotationClickable instance] addPinButtonWithDelegate:self];
[[LDAnnotationClickable instance] recover];

CLLocationCoordinate2D thisCurrentlocation;
 thisCurrentlocation.latitude = [self.strThisCurrentLat doubleValue];

thisCurrentlocation.longitude = [self.strThisCurrentLong doubleValue];


NSLog(@"lat11 lon11 %f %f",thisCurrentlocation.latitude,thisCurrentlocation.longitude);


MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
// set the center of the map region to the now updated map view center
mapRegion.center = self.mapView.centerCoordinate;
mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = thisCurrentlocation.latitude;  // you likely don't need these... just kinda hacked this out
mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = thisCurrentlocation.longitude;
mapView.region=mapRegion;

MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Current Location" andSubTitle:@""andCoordinate:thisCurrentlocation];

newAnnotation.numberID = @"";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
```

Comment: Please symbolicate the crash report. Xcode will do that for you. The hint lies in this line `12  FishCacher  0x0019d0fd 0xe6000 + 749821
`

Comment: When you're in debug session, Xcode should locate the error line for you. Which line did the error appear?

Comment: issue is crash is o occuring on client device not on mine :(

Comment: Though probably not the cause of the crash, the lines that set the latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta don't make sense.  The delta properties are a _height_ and _width_ in degrees -- not an absolute position.  If a user is at lat 50, long 10, making the map width and height that also means map will be zoomed far out.  Set the deltas to some constant like 0.1 or use MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance.

Comment: Actually, it is possible for a negative delta in the span to result in a crash.  For example: if user coordinates are 38,-123 (San Francisco), setting the span to that crashes with "Invalid Region".

Comment: @Anna thanku soo much,this can b the case :) i have changed the code accordingly thanks :)